# How to remove line breaks

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I just do not get why the output does not show correctly

Here is my view code

```
@model IEnumerable<TheSite.Post>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = null;
}
document.write('<table>

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="@p.Url">@p.Title</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>');
```

Here is the output:

```
document.write('<table>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>');
```

Here is the output I need:

```
document.write('<table><tr><td><a href="http://www.test.com">test</a></td></tr></table>');
```

I tried using the stringbuilder but the output was escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it with the `StringBuilder` and use:

```
@Html.Raw(builder.ToString())
```

[**Html.Raw on MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.raw%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)

Comment: I ended up using your code and replacing all line breaks. Thnaks

Answer (score 2):

The View Engine preserves line-breaks and spaces to create legible HTML.

I don't see why you expect them to be removed automagically, but the simple idea would be not to insert them in the first place:

```
  document.write('<table> @foreach (var p in Model){<tr><td> ... }</table>');
```

<strike>Now this probably doesn't compile, just a basic idea.</strike> 
It should compile. Just an ugly layout.

Answer (score 0):

Henk has the right idea in the comments, just put into the string as you want it.

Barring that, you could try using Replace.

```
document.write(mystring.Replace("\n","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stringbuilder with `@Html.Raw()` to avoid escaping of html characters.
You can append "\" character on each of your html line to escape new lines in js, but I wouldn't recommend that. Instead I would use "+"

```
document.write('<table>' + 
 @foreach (var m in Model) {
   '<tr><td>@m</td></tr>'
 }
 + '</table>');
```

Or you could write a helper method which will return an instance of IHtmlString (something like `return new HtmlString(yourStringBuilder.ToString());`

Comment: Just an FYI, Html.Raw does create an instance of IHtmlString.  Creating it yourself isn't necessary (and you don't need MvcHtmlString as of MVC 3...new HtmlString(yourStringBuilder.ToString()); will work just fine (but again, that's what Html.Raw is doing for you.

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't say he could return an IHtmlString in his helper method and then call Html.Raw on it in his view. It wouldn't even compile. He could create an IHtmlString with HtmlHelper.Raw or new HtmlString(). I think Html.Raw method itself creates a new HtmlString()